# How to Read json file and write the change to values of particular key in the same json file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON file named data.json =>

```
  {
    "Name": "Smith",
    "Id": "123"  
       }
```

Now I need to change the Id to 321 using javascript.

How can I do it?

I have tried some code but in vain.

```
let rawdata_one = fs.readFileSync('data.json');
let onedata = JSON.parse(rawdata_one);

 onedata.for(
  function(obj){
  let ob = onedata.findIndex( o => o.Id);
      if(ob == 'Id'){
        onedata[ob].Id= '321';                    
      }
   }
 )

let data = JSON.stringify(onedata);  
fs.writeFileSync('data.json', data);
```

But I am unable to make the changes in the JSON file. Can anyone help in this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
const osarr = onedata['Type']['section']['os'];

osarr.forEach((i)=> {
i['Id'] = 321;
})

console.log(onedata)
```

Comment: Thanks it is working for previous json format. but now The json is simple so how to change your code for simple JSON edited in question. Please can you guide.

Comment: I tried by foreach it says foreach is not a function so i tired for but same issue.

Comment: @Mia please check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) to know more about how JSON works. Try to relate your formate with same and add foreach loop on it

Comment: also [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will tell you how .forEach works, it only works on JSON Array, I think this new **JSON** of yours is not JSON Array

Comment: yes it is not JSON Array. Let me try your suggestions Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this simple JSON,
I did

```
const osarr = onedata
osarr.Id =321
console.log(onedata)
```

It worked